# Expresso Store Download expiry notice conditional?

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using Expresso Store v1 and my client recently added some downloadable products. We've set the [download expiry](https://exp-resso.com/docs/v1/download_tag.html#expire) on these products to 48 hours and we've now made changes to the order confirmation page to encourage customers to download their purchases right away.

However, is there a simple way to produce a 'download expired' notice once the download has expired? Currently the download button just vanishes which has led to a few confused customers!

I suppose I was hoping their might be a conditional '{if expired}' or a parameter that could be used to set a message.

Answer (score 2):

Store doesn't have a built in way to display a message when the download link expires.

I would recommend using something like the [DT Plugin](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dt-plugin) to display an expired message. I haven't used it in a while, but I assume you could do something like this:

```
{if {order_date} < {exp:dt ee_format="false" format="%s" day=“-2”}}
    This link has expired
{/if}
```